# Variable inside a php echo function

Tags: php

I have a php function which displays a rating bar with the arguments. I have a variable called itemID inside my php page which holds the unique item number. I need to send this value to my function and also echo command must stay. Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is the code, which does not work. When I try it on the server, it does not show the id of item, it prints the variable name as it is.

```
<?php echo rating_bar('$as',5) ?>
```

What I get at html file:

```
<div id="unit_long$as">
```

instead of the item id in place of $as.

Comment: Is there a way to explain more clearly?

Comment: show some code what you have already. Have you also tried already?

Comment: <?php echo rating_bar('12t',5); ?>

this is the code, 12t must be changed with $itemID

Comment: You should just put the actual variable in place of 12t. <?php echo rating_bar($itemID,5); ?>

Comment: When I do that, It shows the variable name exactly in the html not the ID.

Comment: Wait, what does the function actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single Quotes do not support variable replace,

```
$as = "test";
echo '$as'; //$as in your end result
echo "$as"; // test in your end result

echo $as; // test in your end result

//For proper use
echo " ".$as." "; // test in your end result
```

Update for newer PHP versions you should now use Template Syntax

```
echo "{$as}"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I get what you are saying, this is what you are asking.

```
<?php echo rating_bar($itemID,5); ?>
```

With the limited code you are providing, thats what looks like you are asking.

Comment: For example this code will return "$as" as result not the number 1. 
<?php
            $as = 1;
           echo rating_bar('$as',5); 
           ?>

Comment: Then have the echo inside the function if you are passing it the variable. And I am also not sure if you are even putting the variable in double quotes.

Comment: @user1124076: why do you enclose variables in quotes?

Comment: Quotes were the problem, it it now fixed. Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, by the way, you need to remember, that when dealing with variables, how you use them depends on whether you should put them in single quotes, double quotes or not.